# Chrome loading pages way off screen (Huge amounts of scroll)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm having the issue where Chrome randomly loads a specific page way of the screen.

I'm running Mac OSX, developing a Backbone.js App, totally client side no PHP/Node.

The page loads off the screen totally so I have to scroll to get it onto the screen correctly, all I can see if the brushed metal effect Chrome gives you when you're off page on bounce.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Developer Tools > Elements (press <kbd>F12</kbd>) to inspect the element and look at it's style properties.

Comment: This seems like more of a comment to me than an answer.

Comment: The DOM is out of view, cannot inspect property.

Comment: Can't. The DOM is off the pag